# GET ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error trying to load LESS CSS Library

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I'm trying to use the LESS CSS library found here http://lesscss.org/.

First step on their front page is to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less" ></script>
```

but I get this error in the console.

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

But if you go straight to https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less it loads just fine.

I'm wondering if it's a browser setting as I tried it on Chrome AND Firefox and same error.  Any help appreciated!

this is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Uno</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less" ></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
  Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a `styles.less` file? I'm guessing you didn't set up an actual `styles.less` file in your directory.

Comment: @disinfor yes I do have the styles.less file

Comment: @disinfor I also tried commenting out the <link> line above to see if it would load just the library itself and it's still not loading and i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Yeah, the JS is looking for a file `styles.less` that doesn't exist. Do you have it in the same directory as you HTML?

Comment: Are you loading it in the browser like `file://` or are you loading via a url like `http`? As a test, I would add `https://` so it is `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/less`. If you are loading in a browser like `file://` leaving out the protocol the browser won't know what to fill in.

Comment: I would highly recommend you read the usage docs: http://lesscss.org/usage/

Comment: @disinfor hm interesting.. i actually have it in "styles/idex.less" so i changed the <link> appropriately to indicate so.. let me try removing the folder structure i guess

Comment: @imvain2 okay i'll try that thanks

Comment: @disinfor changed the folder structure to just load a simple index.less file didn't work.  i read the usage and i downloaded the file and referring to that but now i'm getting a CORS error. sigh.  i'll keep trying though thank you

Comment: @imvain2 i loaded it just as it shows in the post, i tried changing it to https but that didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Do something really simple: create a `styles.less` file in the same folder as your HTML file and add `body { background-color: red; }` Keep the link and script tags exactly as they are in this question. And test if your background is red.

Comment: @disinfor just tried based on your suggest and not working.  i tried using the URL linked in the OP and I tried again changing the src to a local less.js i downloaded from the lesscss.org/usage page and still getting a CORS error when i try locally and i get the File Not Found error if i use the link.

Comment: Directly from the documentation: Due to the same origin policy of browsers, loading external resources requires enabling CORS: https://enable-cors.org/